# Getting text as string from selected item in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, mahapps.metro

I have a ListBox, and I'm trying to get the value of the selected item as a string, but nothing I try seems to work. Here's how I have setup the ListBox and data for it:

```
public class Thing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    }
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Thing> deviceList;

deviceList = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Thing>()
        {
            new Thing{ Name="Amaze", Manufacturer="HTC"},
            new Thing{ Name="One X", Manufacturer="HTC"},
            new Thing{ Name="One X+", Manufacturer="HTC"},
            new Thing{ Name="Moto X", Manufacturer="Motorola"},
            new Thing{ Name="Moto G", Manufacturer="Motorola"},
            new Thing{ Name="OnePlus One", Manufacturer="Other"},
        };
System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView view = System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(deviceList);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new System.Windows.Data.PropertyGroupDescription("Manufacturer"));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Manufacturer", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Name", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
phoneListBox.ItemsSource = view;
```

Here's the XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="phoneListBox" Height="178" Margin="-25,25,5,0" SelectionChanged="phoneListBox_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
 <ListBox.GroupStyle>
   <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
 </ListBox.GroupStyle>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The most common way I've seen is to do:

```
string selected = phoneListBox.GetItemText(phoneListBox.SelectedValue);
```

but VS doesn't recognize GetItemText as a property of ListBox at all.

I've also tried:

```
string selected = phonelistBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

but it doesn't return the actual text of the item.

I'm using WPF with MahApps.Metro UI, so it's possible there ListBox has different attributes than the generic one, but I don't know how that would change things. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: the items in the listbox are objects with the class Things. so if you want the name of the device then you have to use `string selected = phonelistBox.SelectedItem.Name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the name like this in the selectionchanged event,

```
 private void phoneListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    Thing lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Thing);
    string selected = lbi.Name.ToString();
 }
```